# Flutter: How to add item to favourite and display favourites in listview

Tags: flutter

I am working on an e-commerce demo project that uses woocommerce for its backend. I have a product card widget for listing all products displayed in a grid or list view.
This is the code for the product card

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProductDetails(
                      product: data,
                      productName: data.name,
                    )));
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                  width: 160,
                  height: 185,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          data.images[0].src,
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ))),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 7,
              left: 20,
              child: Visibility(
                  visible: data.calculateDiscount() > 0,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        '-${data.calculateDiscount()}%',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ]),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 3,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    data.name,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  data.type == "variable"
                      ? (data.attributes[0].name +
                          ": " +
                          data.attributes[0].options.join("-").toString())
                      : '₦${data.regularPrice}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: data.type == "variable" ? Colors.black : Colors.red,
                    fontSize: data.type == "variable" ? 12 : 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    decoration: data.type == "variable"
                        ? TextDecoration.none
                        : TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Text(
                  data.type == "variable"
                      ? '₦${data.price}'
                      : '₦${data.salePrice}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

How can I integrate add to favourite logic on this product card and display all favourites in a listview? I need to have a favourites page in my app. Thanks

Comment: Probably want to store a users favourite product id's `somewhere`, or possibly more data than just the id, depending on how easy it is to access the data. Then use the favorites list as you like

Comment: @VinceLowe how do I do this? Is there any doc to refer to?